# nuxt js で他のフレームワークを使わず、phpmailer でメール送信したい、静的サイトを出力もしたい

Tags: php, vue.js, nuxt.js, axios

dbを使わず静的サイトを構築をしています。
お問い合わせフォームを作りたいのですが、本番環境はftpサーバなので、node mailerは使えません。
そこでphpmailerを使うことにして、nuxtjs のaxiosでやり取りをしようとしたのですが、
npm run devの環境では何とかエラーなしでrequestを送れているものの、responseがhtmlコードが戻ってきてしまいます。
npm run generate　を叩いて静的サイトを構築してから試したら,undefinedが戻ってきてしまいます。

---

要は↓
*xampp環境でのphpにnuxtからhttp requestを送ってメール送信はxamppからの環境でphpに行ってもらいresponseをnuxtjsに戻したいという考え方です。

*phpファイルはローカルでnuxtが起動しているサーバと別にローカルでのxampp環境で起動されています

> index.vue　(axiosを送ろうととしているvue)

```
<template>
    <div id="contanct" class="container mx-auto my-56 max-w-90">
        <div class="content-title  mb-20">
            <h1 class="text-2xl text-gray-700">お問い合わせ</h1>
            <div class="under-line h-2 w-32 bg-red-300 mb-20"></div>
            <form @submit.prevent="formCheck()" class="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 flex flex-col my-2">
                <div class="-mx-3 md:flex mb-6">
                    <div class="md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
                        <label
                            class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-grey-darker text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                            for="grid-first-name">
                            氏
                        </label>
                        <input
                            v-model="first_name"
                            @keyup="check_invalid('first_name')"
                            class="appearance-none block w-full bg-grey-lighter text-grey-darker border border-grey-lighter rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3"
                            id="grid-last-name"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="佐藤">
                            <p class="text-red text-xs italic">{{ errors.first_name_invalid }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
                        <label
                            class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-grey-darker text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                            for="grid-last-name">
                            名
                        </label>
                        <input
                            @keyup="check_invalid('last_name')"

                            v-model="last_name"
                            class="appearance-none block w-full bg-grey-lighter text-grey-darker border border-grey-lighter rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3"
                            id="grid-last-name"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="本田">
                            <p class="text-red text-xs italic">{{ errors.last_name_invalid }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="-mx-3 md:flex mb-6">
                            <div class="md:w-full px-3">
                                <label
                                    class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-grey-darker text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                                    for="grid-password">
                                    メールアドレス
                                </label>
                                <input
                            @keyup="check_invalid('email_address')"

                                    v-model="email_address"
                                    class="appearance-none block w-full bg-grey-lighter text-grey-darker border border-grey-lighter rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3"
                                    id="grid-password"
                                    type="email"
                                    placeholder="example@example.com">
                                    <p class="text-red text-xs italic">{{ errors.email_address_invalid }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="-mx-3 md:flex mb-6">
                            <div class="md:w-full px-3">
                                <label
                                    class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-grey-darker text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                                    for="grid-password">
                                    メールアドレス
                                </label>
                                <textarea

                                    @keyup="check_invalid('contact_info')"
                                    v-model="contact_info"
                                    class="appearance-none block w-full bg-grey-lighter text-grey-darker border border-grey-lighter rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3"
                                    id="grid-textarea"
                                    placeholder="ご用意を自由に書いてください。。。"
                                    rows="10">
                                </textarea>
                                <p class="text-red text-xs italic">{{ errors.contact_info_invalid }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="inline-block py-3 text-xl text-white shadow bg-green-300">Send</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        env: {
            baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
        },
        head(){
            return{
                title:'お問い合わせ｜わかば会計事務所',
            }
        },
        transition (to, from) {
            if (!from) { return 'slide-left' }
            return +to.query.page < +from.query.page ? 'slide-right' : 'slide-left'
        },
        data(){
            return{
                first_name:'',
                last_name:'',
                email_address:'',
                contact_info:'',
                errors:{
                    first_name_invalid : '',
                    last_name_invalid : '',
                    email_address_invalid : '',
                    contact_info_invalid:''
                }
            }
        },
        methods:{
            formCheck(){

                if(this.first_name == ''){
                   return this.errors.first_name_invalid = '氏は必修項目です';
                }

                if(this.last_name == ''){
                    return this.errors.last_name_invalid = '名は必修項目です';
                }

                if(this.email_address == ''){
                    return this.errors.email_address_invalid = 'メールアドレスは必修項目です';
                }

                if(this.contact_info == ''){
                    return this.errors.contact_info_invalid = '要件も入力してください。';
                }

                //もし全部が入力されたら
                if(this.first_name !== '' && this.last_name !== '' && this.email_address !== '' && this.contact_info !== ''){
                    this.send_data();
                }

            },
            check_invalid(val){
                switch (val) {

                case 'first_name':
                    if(this.errors.first_name_invalid != '' && this.first_name != ''){
                        return this.errors.first_name_invalid = '';
                    }
                break;

                case 'last_name':
                    if(this.errors.last_name_invalid != '' && this.last_name != ''){
                        return this.errors.last_name_invalid = '';
                    }
                break;

                case 'email_address':
                    if(this.errors.email_address_invalid != '' && this.email_address != ''){
                        return this.errors.email_address_invalid = '';
                    }
                break;

                case 'contact_info':
                    if(this.errors.contact_info_invalid != '' && this.contact_info != ''){
                        return this.errors.contact_info_invalid = '';
                    }
                break;

                }

            },
            send_data(){
                let params = new URLSearchParams();
                params.append('text','test');
                axios.post([URL],params
                // {
                //     'first_name' : this.first_name,
                //     'last_name' : this.last_name,
                //     'email_address' : this.email_address,
                //     'contact_info' : this.contact_info,
                // }
                ).then(function (Response) {
                    console.log('res');
                    console.log(Response.data)
                }).catch(error =>{
                    console.log(error.data);
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.text-red{
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

> mail.php 受け取るphpファイル

```
<?php 
echo "hello";

?>
```

> config.nuxt.js

```
.......
  plugins: [
   { src: '~/plugins/axios.js', mode: 'client'}
  ],
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
  },
  proxy:{
    '/send_email' : {target: 'http://localhost:3000', pathRewrite: {'^/vendor/phpmailer': '/'}}
  },
......
```

> axios.js

axios.jsではaxiosの外部アクセス権限をオッケーにしています

```
export default function({ $axios, redirect }) {
    $axios.setToken('access_token')

    $axios.onResponse(config => {
        $axios.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000')
    })
    $axios.onError(error => {
        if(error.response.status === 500) {
            redirect('/404')
        }
    })

    $axios.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', [
        'post'
    ])
}
```

> response.data の結果

```
<!doctype html>
<html >
  <head >
    <title>ashitamo</title><meta data-n-head="1" charset="utf-8"><meta data-n-head="1" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><meta data-n-head="1" data-hid="description" name="description" content="for test nust js"><link data-n-head="1" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/runtime.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/commons.app.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/vendors.app.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app.117ae7e03df8c389b7a6.hot-update.js" as="script">
  </head>
  <body >
    <div id="__nuxt"><style>#nuxt-loading {  visibility: hidden;  opacity: 0;  position: absolute;  left: 0;  right: 0;  top: 0;  bottom: 0;  display: flex;  justify-content: center;  align-items: center;  flex-direction: column;  animation: nuxtLoadingIn 10s ease;  -webkit-animation: nuxtLoadingIn 10s ease;  animation-fill-mode: forwards;  overflow: hidden;}@keyframes nuxtLoadingIn {  0% {visibility: hidden;opacity: 0;  }  20% {visibility: visible;opacity: 0;  }  100% {visibility: visible;opacity: 1;  }}@-webkit-keyframes nuxtLoadingIn {  0% {visibility: hidden;opacity: 0;  }  20% {visibility: visible;opacity: 0;  }  100% {visibility: visible;opacity: 1;  }}#nuxt-loading>div,#nuxt-loading>div:after {  border-radius: 50%;  width: 5rem;  height: 5rem;}#nuxt-loading>div {  font-size: 10px;  position: relative;  text-indent: -9999em;  border: .5rem solid #F5F5F5;  border-left: .5rem solid #fff;  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);  transform: translateZ(0);  -webkit-animation: nuxtLoading 1.1s infinite linear;  animation: nuxtLoading 1.1s infinite linear;}#nuxt-loading.error>div {  border-left: .5rem solid #ff4500;  animation-duration: 5s;}@-webkit-keyframes nuxtLoading {  0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);  }  100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);transform: rotate(360deg);  }}@keyframes nuxtLoading {  0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);  }  100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);transform: rotate(360deg);  }}</style><script>window.addEventListener('error', function () {  var e = document.getElementById('nuxt-loading');  if (e) {e.className += ' error';  }});</script><div id="nuxt-loading" aria-live="polite" role="status"><div>Loading...</div></div></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_nuxt/runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/_nuxt/commons.app.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/_nuxt/vendors.app.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/_nuxt/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**解決できました**

html文が帰ってきてしまうのは同じnuxtが動いて環境のサーバにrequestが行ってしまっているからでした、つまりurlがあってなかったからでした。

$axios.$postするときJSON.stringify()でデータを囲んで上げないCORSエラーが出てそこでもう一段階ハマりました。